# Can we execute the code beyond the time limit of 30 sec when extracting data from forum site?

Tags: php

I have a DOM web crawler in php and it works fine. all it does is to extract the mentioned specific class statements from a forum site and echo them in my php page.

So, since the forum site has more than 1000+ post, the DOM parser code extracts upto a limit and prints a error as `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\usmlemed\dom\simple_html_dom.php on line 75`

so, how can i make the execution time to go till all statements are parsed?

Comment: Yes, it's in the PHP documentation how to do it.  By the way, crawling is something better done off-line by a cron job than interactively via a web app.  Hint: The default timeout doesn't apply to PHP scripts running from the commandline by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set_time_limit` to set a limit for the whole processing. This is obviously to be set in the beginning of the script

```
set_time_limit(3600);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php